# Vorticity for the Navier-Stokes equations

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics, parabolic-pde

The definition that I know of is the vorticity $\omega$ is the curl of the velocity $u$. Now I'm reading a note saying $\omega$ is defined to be the $d\times d$ antisymmetric matrix: $$\omega = \frac{1}{2}[\nabla u - (\nabla u)^{T}]$$
especially in $2D$, $\omega = \partial_{1}u_{2}- \partial_{2}u_{1}$.

I couldn't derive why the 2D form is related to the definition by antisymmetric matrix. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In dimension two, every antisymmetric matrix is of the form
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
0 & a \\
 -a & 0\end{pmatrix}.
$$
In particular, it is a one-dimensional space. So there is little harm in making the identification
$$ a \leftrightarrow a \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
 -1 & 0\end{pmatrix}. $$
Indeed, if you actually computed the difference of the matrices, since $ \nabla u =\begin{pmatrix}
\partial_1 u_1  & \partial_2 u_1 \\
 \partial_1 u_2 & \partial_2 u_2\end{pmatrix},  $
you would see that

$$ \omega_{matrix} = \frac12 \omega_{scalar}\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
 -1 & 0\end{pmatrix} $$
the factor of $\frac12$ is frequently inconsequential.

Comment: After a second thought, what's the difference here between $\omega_{matrix}$ and $\omega_{scalar}$?

Comment: @Bourne Almost nothing? One's a matrix and one's a scalar, thats about it

Comment: @Bourne if you have a more specific question, I'd be more than happy to help